# How to mock enum using Mockito only?

Tags: caching, enums, mockito

I have a singleton cache which i have created using enum. I want to mock the add and retrieve methods of the cache. I can use Mockito only (not Powermockito).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? Mocking enums is a terrible idea. Can you provide some code? That way maybe it would be possible to help you rewrite that can be tested without hacks?

Comment: Enums can't be mocked with Mockito alone because they are `final` types. Whether mocking an enum makes sense or not depends on whether the enum type defines non-trivial methods. Without some example code, there is no way to tell.

Comment: public class Test {
    
    public void sendToDownstream(){
        //do something
        Send.INSTANCE.send();
    }
    
}

enum Send{
    INSTANCE;
    
    public void send(){
        //do something
    }
}                Now i want to test sendToDownstream method for which i need to mock enum to simulate send method.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: Not yet, i have to use powermockito only